# Shift invariance and Krylov subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ a matrix, and $r_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Also, let $(\sigma)_i$ a sequence of complex scalars.

Consider the Krylov subspace $K_n(A,r_0)=\text{span} \{r_0,A r_0, \ldots, A^{n-1}r_0 \}$.

I want to show that $$K_n(A + \sigma_j I,r_0) = K_n(A+\sigma_i I,r_0)$$ i.e. the so-called "*shift invariance of Krylov subspaces"*

---

I consider $x \in K_n({A+\sigma_i I})$, therefore $$x= \sum_k^{n-1} \alpha_k (A+\sigma_i I)^k r_0$$

I search for scalars $\beta_k$ such that $$\sum_k^{n-1} \alpha_k (A+\sigma_i I)^k r_0 = \sum_k^{n-1} \beta_k (A+\sigma_j I)^k r_0$$

and therefore I obtain

$$\sum_k^{n-1} \Bigl( \alpha_k (A+\sigma_i I)^k - \beta_k (A+\sigma_j I)^k \Bigr) r_0$$

But now I don't know how to find $\beta_k$.

How can I move? Also other ways are really appreciated

Comment: "I consider $x \in K_n(A+\sigma_jI)$" did you mean $\sigma_i$?

Comment: yes, of course. thanks

Comment: You can view $K_n(A,v)$ as $\{p(A)b : \deg p < n\}$. It is essentially clear that a polynomial in $A-\sigma I$ is also a polynomial in $A$, which is the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that for any $\sigma$, we have $K(A + \sigma I, r_0) \subset K(A,r_0)$. To that end, we note by the binomial theorem that for any $0 \leq k\leq n-1$, we have
$$
(A + \sigma I)^k = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom kj \sigma^{k-j}A^jr_0 \in \operatorname{span}\operatorname{span}\{A^k r_0 : 0 \leq k \leq n-1\} = K(A,r_0).
$$
Since this holds for all $k$, conclude that $\operatorname{span}\{(A + \sigma I)^ k : 0 \leq k \leq n-1\} \subset K(A,r_0)$, which is what we wanted.

---

With that, note that
$$
K(A + \sigma_j I,r_0) \supset K([A + \sigma_j I] + (\sigma_i - \sigma_j)I,r_0) = K(A + \sigma_i I,r_0).
$$
By symmetry (i.e. by switching $i$ and $j$), we see that the reverse inclusion holds as well.

Comment: I think you wanted to write $\operatorname{span}\{(A + \sigma I)^ k r_0 : 0 \leq k \leq n-1\} \subset K(A,r_0)$ in the third line @BenGrossmann

Comment: Also, I can't understand how the inclusion
$$K(A + \sigma_j I,r_0) \subset K([A + \sigma_j I] + (\sigma_i - \sigma_j)I,r_0)$$

follows from the previous point.

Comment: I think I got it: you used the binomial expansion applied to $$\Bigl( [A + \sigma_j I] + (\sigma_i - \sigma_j)I  \Bigr)^k$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann The shift invariance does not depend on the symmtry of $A$,right? I mean, in the proof you don't assume it, right?

Comment: @Vefhug That is correct

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks. Also, I can't understand why from $K(A + \sigma I, r_0) \subset K(A,r_0)$ we obtain  $$K(A + \sigma_j I,r_0) \subset K([A + \sigma_j I] + (\sigma_i - \sigma_j)I,r_0)$$ Could you be a bit more precise?

Comment: @Vefhug I had the direction of inclusion backwards; see my edit. Let $B = A + \sigma_jI$ and $\tau = \sigma_i - \sigma_j$. Because $K(A + \sigma I, r_0) \subset K(A,r_0)$ holds for any $A,\sigma$, we have $K(B + \tau I,r_0) \subset K(B,r_0)$.